# ASP.NET Core - want to force text/plain with Results.Ok(<string>)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

Trying to replicate a Framework API using .NET Core 6 and minimal APIs.
One thing is I am getting "application/json" as the content-type if I return `Results.Ok(data)`.

Yes it should be json, but this is replicating legacy functionality.
I can get the results to be text/plain if I just use `return data;`.

But would like to use `Results` if I can.

Setting this does not work:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
return Results.Ok(data);
```

Still comes back `application/json`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a custom `IResult` type for text/plain

```
class PlainTextResult : IResult
{
    private readonly string _text;

    public PlainTextResult(string text)
    {
        _text = text;
    }

    public Task ExecuteAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
        httpContext.Response.ContentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(_text);
        return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(_text);
    }
}
```

Then you just return that in your MapGet like so

```
app.MapGet("/text", () =>  new PlainTextResult("This is plain text"));
```

As a side note, there is also the result type of `Text` that takes a content type parameter

```
return Results.Text("This is plain text", "text/plain", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: I am using app.MapGet()   Any idea how to make that work?

Comment: Updated answer with how to do it in minimal api, you should probably specify that when creating your question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use `Results.Json`:

```
Results.Json(data, contentType:"text/plain");
```